# SQL: Combining Main and Sub Data in a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

In `Sql Server 2008`, I try to use [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview), I have two table and I have some data like this;

**JIRAISSUE**

[image]

**ISSUELINK**

[image]

In this example ID=16554 is a `Main Task`. 16555 and 16556 are `Sub Tasks` of 16554. As you can see in `JIRAISSUE` ,main task and all sub tasks are an issue. And they connected in `ISSUELINK` table, in `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION` columns.

I try to write a query like this but I failed. I try to find a result like this ;

[image]

As you can see in the picture, What I want is; showing one row based all main tasks and their sub tasks.

I can't find the right query for this. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand - are you saying that you want a result that consists of a single row that includes the main task and an arbitrary number of subtasks?  If so, I don't think that is possible, it is fundamentally a multiple row result.  Also, do you need the answer to recurse - i.e. include sub tasks of subtasks?

Comment: Not arbitrary. They connected as you can see in `ISSUELINK` table. There is no subtasks of subtasks. One main task has two subtask. And I want combine them.

Comment: Are there always 2 subtasks (no more no less)? If so extend @Kip Real query by: adding condition "and i.sequence = 0" to first inner join, add another copy of issuelink and jiraissue joins (i2 and j3), add condition "and i2.sequence = 1" to the second issuelink join, add j3.summary/created/updated/resolutiondate to the select...

Comment: @Goran sub task could 1 or 2. Not more. But I don' understand clearly your query. Should I use 3 INNER JOIN? Can you write an answer for your thinking query?

Comment: I tried this query but it gets no data `SELECT  j.ID, j.Pkey, j.SUMMARY, j.CREATED,j.UPDATED, j.RESOLUTIONDATE
        ,j2.SUMMARY, j2.CREATED,j2.UPDATED, j2.RESOLUTIONDATE, j3.SUMMARY, j3.CREATED, j3.UPDATED, j3.RESOLUTIONDATE
FROM Jira.jiraissue As j
INNER JOIN Jira.issuelink i
    ON i.SOURCE =j.ID 
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2
    ON i.DESTINATION =j2.ID and i.SEQUENCE = 0
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j3
    ON i.DESTINATION =j3.ID and i.SEQUENCE = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT j.ID, j.Pkey, j.SUMMARY, j.CREATED, j.UPDATED, j.RESOLUTIONDATE 
       ,j2.SUMMARY, j2.CREATED, j2.UPDATED, j2.RESOLUTIONDATE
       ,j3.SUMMARY, j3.CREATED, j3.UPDATED, j3.RESOLUTIONDATE 
FROM Jira.jiraissue As j 
INNER JOIN Jira.issuelink i 
        ON i.SOURCE = j.ID  and i.SEQUENCE = 0
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2 
        ON i.DESTINATION = j2.ID
LEFT JOIN Jira.issuelink i2 
        ON i2.SOURCE = j.ID  and i2.SEQUENCE = 1
LEFT JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j3 
        ON i2.DESTINATION = j3.ID
```

The left joins support cases where there's only one issue.

Comment: Goran, that case, if main task has no sub task, main task not getting result of the query. It's getting only main task has one or more sub task on the result. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Then also use LEFT JOIN on i and j2. Inner join will return records only if matching records exist in joined table. Left join will return records even if no matching records exist in joined table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  j.ID, j.Pkey, j.SUMMARY, j.CREATED,j.UPDATEED, j.RESOLUTIONDATE
        ,j2.SUMMARY, j2.CREATED,j2.UPDATEED, j2.RESOLUTIONDATE
FROM @JIRAISSUE As j
INNER JOIN @ISSUELINK i
    ON i.SOURCE =j.ID
INNER JOIN @JIRAISSUE As j2
    ON i.DISTINATION =j2.ID
```

Comment: Your query looks great. But It gets the results with two rows. Not one. It generates a row for each sub tasks. (For 16555 and 16556). Look at this picture: http://i.imgur.com/6pzik.jpg How can show them for only one row ?